# Supremum Exam Question

Tags: calculus, supremum-and-infimum

I had a calculus exam and one of the questions (apparently an easy one ) had a lot of issues and our professor even emailed and said that most of the students didn't answer it correct with a formal proof.

I would like to ask for assistance of writing a formal proof for this question.

The question :

Let $A$ be a set containing at least 2 members.
Prove that:

$\sup\{A\}>\sup\{A\setminus {x}\} \Rightarrow \sup\{A\}=x$

My try on this one:

Intuitively I understand why it is like that. 
Starting with negating the proposition 3

Answer (score 1):

I'd prove the contrapositive$\ldots$

Lemma: Suppose that $A$ is a nonempty subset of $\mathbb{R}$ which is bounded above, that $x\in A$, and that $x\neq\sup A$. In this case, $A\setminus\{x\}$ is nonempty and bounded above, and $\sup (A\setminus\{x\})=\sup A$.

Proof: $A\setminus\{x\}$ is nonempty because otherwise we'd have $A=\{x\}$ giving $\sup A=x$.

Since $A\setminus\{x\}\subset A$, we see that $A\setminus\{x\}$ is bounded above and $\sup(A\setminus\{x\})\leq\sup A$. (This is quick enough to prove.)

To show $\sup A\leq\sup(A\setminus\{x\})$ we need to show that $\sup(A\setminus\{x\})$ is an upper bound for $A$.

Take $a\in A$. Either $a\in A\setminus\{x\}$ or $a=x$. In the first case, $a\leq\sup(A\setminus\{x\})$ by definition of $\sup$. In the second we argue as follows. Since $a=x\neq\sup A$, we have $a<\sup A$ and we can find a $b\in A$ with $a<b$; we see $b\in A\setminus\{x\}$ so that $a<b\leq\sup(A\setminus\{x\})$, as required.

Comment: Nice answer! +!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this can be proved by contradiction.

If $x \in A$ and $x < \sup A$, then there exists at least one $y \in A$ closer to $\sup A$ than $x$ is.  (That's by the definition of $\sup A$.)  Thus, we have
$$
x < y \leq \sup A,
$$
and, consequently, removing $x$ from $A$ does not affect the $\sup A$; i.e.,
$$
\sup(A) = \sup(A \setminus \{x\}).
$$

Comment: I know this ! this was my explanation as well but was counted as not formal enough, is there any more formal proof you could please provide me with?

Comment: @user313448 It's unrealistic to expect feedback on whether your answer was graded appropriately. That depends on _exactly_ what you wrote - you say you did the above, but surely you're not saying that every word and symbol was identical to what avs said. The proper grading also depends on the context - what was done during class, what was assigned, how similar homework problems wer graded...

Comment: I know what you mean, maybe I stated my request wrongly - is there a more formal way to write this proof.

Comment: I don't see what ambiguity my argument has.  Maybe your instructor just wanted more notation and less prose, meaning by "formal" the presentation rather than the content.  A formalization fetish, unfortunately, afflicts much of the mathematical community.

If $x \in A$ and if $x < \sup A$, then $\sup A$ has a left-sided neighborhood, $U_{\epsilon} = ] (\sup A) - \epsilon, \sup A]$, that does not contain $x$.  This neighborhood, by the definition of $\sup A$, must contain at least one element $y$ of $\sup A$.  By construction,
$x < y \leq \sup A$, so $\sup A = \sup (A \setminus \{x\})$.